# Error con descripción de mensaje html al exportar EXCEL en ASP.NET, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, razor, webforms

Estoy trabajando en asp.net MVC con webform(similar a razor), y quiero exportar a Excel algunos datos de una tabla, pero sale un error que solo me dice la descripción de una tabla en html, lo cual no me dice nada donde está el error. El error que muestra es el siguiente:
[image: el tipo de error]

En mi controller tengo el siguiente código para exportar a Excel:

```
<HttpPost>
Function ExportarPDF() As ActionResult
    Try 
        Using db As New BD_LOSCOPIHUESEntities1
            Dim gv = New GridView()
            gv.DataSource = db.PERSONAS.ToList
            gv.DataBind()

            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls")
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"

            Response.Charset = ""
            Dim objStringWriter As New StringWriter()
            Dim objHtmlTextWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter)

            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter)

            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
        Return Json(1)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    Return Json(2)
    End Try        
 End Function
```

Me gustaría saber como soluciono el error para exportar a Excel, quizás me falte agregar algo al webconfig, o usar alguna otra forma de exportar a Excel. Además, me gustaría saber como podría exportar solo las columnas que yo quiero de una tabla, y no todas que provengan de la Base de Datos. Y también como agregar títulos, fecha o alguna descripción en el encabezado y en el pied del Excel. Saludos

Comment: El mensaje de error no me dice cual es el problema, sin embargo te comento otro posible problema: esa imagen que tratas de exportar tiene una ruta relativa a la página web (i.e. no está realmente dentro del archivo de Excel); para que la imagen funcione tienen que estar embebida (e.g. como Base64).

Comment: lo que quiero exportar es solamente contenido que extraigo desde el controller de una tabla, no tiene nada que ver lo que aparece nombre,apellido, edad